# Send link to second app from Air for iOs app

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, url-scheme

My question is simple, in de ios sdk you can create a custom url scheme for your application, simply illustrated in the docs as so:

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"todolist://www.acme.com?Quarterly%20Report#200806231300"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];
```

My native application has this such a scheme system set up, however, the app is going to have to be called from an air for ios (flash) application. My question to the stack is this, how would I call this url from actionscript, and (if this is not possible), is there anyway I can do this natively from inside the air for ios application?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

This should work just using navigateToURL within AS3.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#navigateToURL()

Comment: Thanks for your answer, we have tried to use this with "itms-services" for updating our application, however this did not seem to work. Could you maybe give an example?

Comment: This will work as David says in AIR 3. Before AIR 3, the navigateToURL function has a short "whitelist" of the permitted URI schemes. In AIR 3 this whitelist has been removed.